# Importing MockMultipartFile is not working, am I using the right dependencies?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

While trying to use MockMultipartFile it doesn't seem to find it via dependencies, so I have to add it to class path manually every time after building, I can't seem to figure it out.

testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '5.1.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '5.1.8.RELEASE'

is what I use.

Comment: Please mention the stack trace.

Comment: there is no stacktrace, it just doesnt import it automatically..